An application of Grotendieck spectral sequence and Leray spectral sequence
I was reading the paper Minimal models for Kähler threefolds by Prof. Höring and Peternell. In page 8 of the paper has the following arguement using Grotendieck spectral sequence and Leray spectral sequence:
Let $\varphi:X\to Y$ be a proper bimeromorphic morphism between compact normal complex space with rational singularities, and for both $X$ and $Y$ there exist a modification to Kahler manifold (i.e. they are in Fujiki class).
Then the paper says:

Since $Y$ has only rational singularities and $\varphi$ is bimeromorphic, the Grothendieck spectral sequence immediately yields
$$
R^q \varphi_*\left(\mathcal{O}_X\right)=0
$$
for $q \geq 1$. Consequently $R^1 \varphi_*(\mathbb{R})=0$, so the Leray spectral sequence yields an exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow H^2(Y, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^2(X, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^0\left(Y, R^2 \varphi_*(\mathbb{R})\right)
$$

Here is the questions:
(1) The paper says since $Y$ has only rational singularity and $\varphi$ is bimeromorphic, by Grotendieck spetral sequence it imedidate implies $$R^q\varphi_*(\mathcal{O}_X) = 0,\quad q \ge 1$$
why Grotendieck spectral sequence implies this?
(2) As a consequence $R^1\varphi_*\mathbb{R} = 0$,
Why $R^q\varphi_*(\mathcal{O}_X) = 0,\ q \ge 1$ implies vanishing $R^1\varphi_*\mathbb{R} = 0$
(3) so the Leray spectral sequence implies the sequence is exact: $$0\to H^2(Y,\mathbb{R})\to H^2(X,\mathbb{R})\to H^0(Y,R^2\varphi_*\mathbb{R})$$
how to use Leray spectral sequence here, I try to apply the five term exact sequence here but I found it's not the five term exact sequence?

I found the solution for the problem (2), which has been proved by Proposition 12.1.1 and 12.1.3. in Classification of Three-Dimensional Flips Kollár  and Mori

For problem (1) it seems that I have discussed it before https://mathoverflow.net/q/460087/97016
